# Membership due change over time

Tags: civimember

I have a lifetime membership running for my organization. The dues for the membership have changed over time and will change over time in future. I want to classify everyone as a life member but at the same time track the different amount paid by different members based on the time of their enrollment.

I can use the price set option to enter multiple price for same membership.  How I go about it?

Edited for clarification : the membership amount was X in 2000 , then it increased to X+Y in 2010, then it increases some more in 2015 like that. But all are under the same scheme. Just that in due course of time, the membership dues was increased by the organization. It is not an annual payment model. Once the desired payment is completed, thats it. There is no renewal. They are members for lifetime

Comment: Not sure I'm following your logic of keeping them all under one memebrship type if they pay different amounts etc? Why wouldn't you put them under different membership types and also make them annual - if thats the period they are members for?

Comment: the membership amount was X in 2000 , then it increased to X+Y in 2010, then it increases some more in 2015 like that. But all are under the same scheme. Just that in due course of time, the membership dues was increased by the organization. ..

Comment: Ah. I was just writing up an answer when the penny dropped. Your memberships are Lifetime but require an annual payment. I think if that is the case you need to make it clear in your question, ie the membership amount 'per year' was X in 2000, and people who signed up in 2000 will pay that amount throughout their lifetime. is that what you mean?

Comment: Also i think you need to clarify how payments/renewals are being handled. If people are renewing when you send out an email, then you could send a link to a different page based on when they joined, and hence how much they paid. hence person who signed up in 2000 will go to page showing $X and person who signed up in 2015 will see amount $Y.

Comment: It is not an annual payment model. Once the desired payment is completed, thats it. There is no renewal. They are members for lifetime.

Comment: Not sure about anyone else but I'm totally confused by the subscription model! So lets ask another question - if in 2010 they dont pay X+Y do they stop being members? Does everyone have to pay the extra in 2010? The model needs to be clear before you map it into CiviCRM or any system for that matter!

Comment: Model is quite simple. May be my explanation made it complex...

Comment: the institution increases the member dues over time. whoever pays that amount during that time become members for lifetime. no renewal needed.  It is one time payment. example : 2000 - 100 INR ;  2010 - 300 INR - 2015 - 500 INR ...    people who become lifetime members from 2000 - 2009 will be paying Rs.100 once . people who become lifetime members from 2010 - 2014 will be paying Rs.300 once.  people who become lifetime members from 2015 - till it changes will be paying Rs.500 once.

Comment: so wont using the minimum fee do the trick? The historical stuff should have a membership contribution related to it so that should reflect what the person paid at the time? CiviCRM doesn't currently support price based on date range so showing a history of the membership type's increases wouldn't be possible in its current form.

Comment: ended up creating a price set with different price field. Only the latest will be active. Others will be used for entering the old data.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you want a Lifetime membership type with its minimum fee to level up every "x" years. Similar to purchasing a Gold - you can have it for lifetime but its price just increases with time.

If this is what you want, simply create a membership type from `Administer -> CiviMember -> Membership Type` with duration set to lifetime and write a custom code in extension/module which increases the minimum fee value of this membership type id with time in year.

Refererence for creating an extension - https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/master/extensions/civix/